# Google Cloud not working on Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hey thanks for helping me out.
I install google-cloud with npm, just like:

```
npm install --save google-cloud
```

then I implement in my code like that:

```
var gcloud =  require('google-cloud')({
  projectId: "czernitzki-148120",
  keyFilename: './service.json' 
});
```

I created a key on a new Service Account that has `Owner` access rights and put the file in service.json. `service.json` is in the same directory as the file that has the code above. After I start the application, it blows up when it reaches the code from above

```
Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/protobufjs/dist/ProtoBuf.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\ByteBuffer\dist\ByteBufferAB.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `bytebuffer`.

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/protobufjs/dist/ProtoBuf.js 25:8-39

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/bytebuffer/dist/ByteBufferAB.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\Long\dist\Long.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `long`.

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/bytebuffer/dist/ByteBufferAB.js 26:8-33

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/JSONStream/index.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\JSONStream\index.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/@google-cloud/prediction/src/model.js 25:17-38

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/osenv/osenv.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\osenv

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/osenv/osenv.js 3:11-35

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/uid-number/uid-number.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\uid-number

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/uid-number/uid-number.js 9:20-44

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js
Module not found: 'aws-sdk' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/info.js 14:14-32

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js
Module not found: 'aws-sdk' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/publish.js 17:14-32

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/testbinary.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/testbinary.js 10:9-33

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js
Module not found: 'aws-sdk' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/unpublish.js 15:14-32

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 9:9-33

Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js
Module not found: 'child_process' in C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\auth

 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js 21:11-35
```

I am using React with `create-react-app`. I've tested it on Windows and the Google Compute Engine. It didn't work on both.

I followed the guide from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node and https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.3.0/storage.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`google-cloud` is a back-end module, and should be used with Node.js, not the front-end.

As mentioned by the comments on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474558/how-to-use-google-cloud-storage-with-react-js), use Google's [front-end api client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do npm install for the modules that are not found,like the following :

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

For the first two errors regarding **CaseSensitivePathsPlugin**,you can find the solution at [Case Sensitive Paths - Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/Urthen/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin)

Comment: I still get this error
Error in ./~/google-cloud/~/JSONStream/index.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\phili\Documents\GitHub\venos\node_modules\google-cloud\node_modules\JSONStream\index.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
 @ ./~/google-cloud/~/@google-cloud/prediction/src/model.js 25:17-38

after it the module errors follow altough I installed child_process manually

Comment: Please check my updated answer regarding CaseSensitivePathsPlugin

Comment: I don't think that can be the solution because create-react-app doesn't allow a webpack config as mentioned here https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/99 also I am still getting the modules error after installing them.