# How to use Google Cloud Storage with react.js?

Tags: express, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I'm running a react.js app that runs on Express. I added the [google-cloud npm module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node), yet I haven't managed to make it work. When I require the module, I get the following error in my console:

[image]

It seems the npm module is expected to run server-side, yet react.js runs client-side. Has anyone tried uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage with a react.js app?

Comment: The `google-cloud` package is seemed need to be run with nodejs but not browsers.

Comment: You can't use that package on the client. Try the [Javascript Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) instead, which is currently in beta.

Comment: I wrote down something about deploying React to Google Cloud Storage here if you are interested https://www.ackee.cz/blog/en/how-to-host-static-react-apps-in-google-storage-bucket-behind-cloudflare-cdn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a JavaScript client library for Google APIs you can use with Google Cloud Platform. [Here's a tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/javascript-guide) that shows you how to use it with Compute Engine APIs. The principles for using it with Google Cloud Storage should be similar.

[Your OAuth API scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#storagev1) need to match the Cloud Storage JSON API, and you'll need to [load](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#----gapiclientloadname----version----callback--) a `storage` client instead of `compute`. From there you can use the [Cloud Storage JSON API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/storage/storage/v1/) as needed, in the same style as the tutorial uses [the Compute Engine API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/compute/compute/v1/).

Comment: Yes; and the underlying issue here is that OP is trying to use a Node-specific npm module in a React application, which won't have access to `fs` and other Node.js core modules from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use firebase to easily access your cloud storage in any react app

```
npm install firebase
```

then import and use it like any other library

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage"


var firebaseConfig = [a key you get from your firebase project]


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var storage = firebase.storage();
```

and use it however you like. eg.

```
var files = await storage.ref("/images").list();
console.log(files.items);
```

simply lists files in your cloud storage folder named `images`

you can get full documentation here [Get started with cloudstorage on web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start), for frontend web usage, like you are intending to work with in react